# Save choice in database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm doing a program where I try to save data every time the user press '`submit`'. I have managed to save in my table '`answers`' the data of the columns: `exercise_id_fk`, `student_id` and `difficulty_student`, but I can not save the data from the column: `choice_answer`. Every time I try to save it, it stops me from saving the other columns. I'm trying to store in the database multiple choice answers. Can you help me see what is wrong?

This is my program where im trying to store in the column '`choice_anser`' from the multiple choice answers:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "project";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
/*echo*/ $id=$_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM exercises where exercise_id='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql); /*Check connection*/
?>

<div id="centered_B" class="header">

<?php
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo '<h1>' . $row["exercise_id"]. ". " . $row["title"] . '</h1>' . "<br>" . '<p>' . $row["text"] . '</p> <img width="603" height="auto" src="' . $row["image_path"] . '"><br><br>

<form method="post" >
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "1" /><img src="' . $row["image_path_A"] . '"/><br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "2" /><img src="' . $row["image_path_B"] . '"><br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "3" /><img src="' . $row["image_path_C"] . '"><br>';
echo '</form>';

/*var_dump($id)*/
?>

    <br><br><br><!--- Select difficulty --->

    <p2>Select difficulty level:</p2>

    <form action='' method='post'>
    <select name="choose" id="choose">>
        <option value="1" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="1") { echo "selected"; } ?> >1</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="2") { echo "selected"; } ?> >2</option>
        <option value="3" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="3") { echo "selected"; } ?> >3</option>
        <option value="4" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="4") { echo "selected"; } ?> >4</option>
        <option value="5" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="5") { echo "selected"; } ?> >5</option>
    </select>

    <br><br><br><!--- Button --->

<!--        <button class="buttonSubmit" >Submit</button>-->
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        <button class="buttonNext" >Next Question</button>
    </form>

</div><!--- end of centered_B div --->



<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
   $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$user_id'";
if(isset($_POST['choice'])){
    if(isset($_POST['choose'])){
        $choice_answer=$_POST['choice'];
        $difficulty=$_POST['choose'];
//      */$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];*/
        $query = "INSERT INTO answers (exercise_id_fk, student_id, difficulty_student, choice_answer) VALUES ('$id','$user_id', '$difficulty', '$choice_answer')";
        $sql=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    }
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "project";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
/*echo*/ $id=$_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM exercises where exercise_id='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql); /*Check connection*/
?>

<div id="centered_B" class="header">

<?php
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
?>

<h1><?php echo $row["exercise_id"] ?></h1><br/>
<p><?php echo $row["text"] ?></p>
<img width="603" height="auto" src="<?php $row["image_path"]?>"><br/><br/>
<form action='' method='post'>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "1" /><img src="<?php echo $row["image_path_A"]; ?>"/><br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "2" /><img src="<?php echo $row["image_path_B"] ; ?>"><br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "3" /><img src="<?php echo $row["image_path_C"]; ?>"><br>


<!-- var_dump($id) -->


    <br><br><br>

    <p2>Select difficulty level:</p2>

    <form action='' method='post'>
    <select name="choose" id="choose">>
        <option value="1" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="1") { echo "selected"; } ?> >1</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="2") { echo "selected"; } ?> >2</option>
        <option value="3" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="3") { echo "selected"; } ?> >3</option>
        <option value="4" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="4") { echo "selected"; } ?> >4</option>
        <option value="5" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="5") { echo "selected"; } ?> >5</option>
    </select>

    <br><br><br><!--- Button --->

       <button class="buttonSubmit" >Submit</button>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        <button class="buttonNext" >Next Question</button>
    </form>

</div><!--- end of centered_B div --->



<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
   $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$user_id'";
if(isset($_POST['choice'])){
    if(isset($_POST['choose'])){
        $choice_answer=$_POST['choice'];
        $difficulty=$_POST['choose'];
//      */$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];*/
        $query = "INSERT INTO answers (exercise_id_fk, student_id, difficulty_student, choice_answer) VALUES ('$id','$user_id', '$difficulty', '$choice_answer')";
        $sql=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I dont know why it doesnt show the images as before with this new code. However it works to store the choice part in the database as I wanted

Comment: You are missing an error in the images. To display them

Comment: Now it will show images too I edit it. if it works then you can mark it as approved

Comment: Yes! It works now! Thank you very much :D I will mark your answer.

Comment: I am glad! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the single form if you want to save everything when you click on submit.

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "project";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
/*echo*/ $id=$_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM exercises where exercise_id='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql); /*Check connection*/
?>

<div id="centered_B" class="header">

<?php
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo '<h1>' . $row["exercise_id"]. ". " . $row["title"] . '</h1>' . "<br>" . '<p>' . $row["text"] . '</p> <img width="603" height="auto" src="' . $row["image_path"] . '"><br><br>




/*var_dump($id)*/
?>

    <br><br><br><!--- Select difficulty --->

    <p2>Select difficulty level:</p2>

    <form action='' method='post'>
 <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "1" /><img src="<?php $row["image_path_A"];?>"/><br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "2" /><img src="<?php $row["image_path_B"];?>"><br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "3" /><img src="<?php $row["image_path_C"];?>"><br>

    <select name="choose" id="choose">
        <option value="1" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="1") { echo "selected"; } ?> >1</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="2") { echo "selected"; } ?> >2</option>
        <option value="3" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="3") { echo "selected"; } ?> >3</option>
        <option value="4" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="4") { echo "selected"; } ?> >4</option>
        <option value="5" <?php if($row["difficulty"]=="5") { echo "selected"; } ?> >5</option>
    </select>

    <br><br><br><!--- Button --->

<!--        <button class="buttonSubmit" >Submit</button>-->
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        <button class="buttonNext" >Next Question</button>
    </form>

</div><!--- end of centered_B div --->



<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
   $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$user_id'";
if(isset($_POST['choice'])){
    if(isset($_POST['choose'])){
        $choice_answer=$_POST['choice'];
        $difficulty=$_POST['choose'];
//      */$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];*/
        $query = "INSERT INTO answers (exercise_id_fk, student_id, difficulty_student, choice_answer) VALUES ('$id','$user_id', '$difficulty', '$choice_answer')";
        $sql=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Im trying your code but im having a problem when deleting the 3 "choice" answers from <?php ?>, do you know whats the problem?

Comment: The error I have is this one: Parse error: `syntax error, unexpected '' method='' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'`

Comment: What you want to delete send me the code you want to delete, probably it left with the end or beginning of PHP code

Comment: `<?php
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo '<h1>' . $row["exercise_id"]. ". " . $row["title"] . '</h1>' . "<br>" . '<p>' . $row["text"] . '</p> <img width="603" height="auto" src="' . $row["image_path"] . '"><br><br>;
/*var_dump($id)*/
?>`

Comment: I post your code to try it in PHPSTORM and it had some errors I dont know how to solve them. Can you help me?

Comment: I also need to have the 3 choices inside <?php ?>, because its getting information from a database

Comment: Its not working... I neet to have the Choice part inside the first php code

Comment: Wait I try and give you solution

Comment: Ok, it works now when I save the CHOICE in the database, but now my program does not collect the data IMAGES from the database. This was done on the line: `<?php
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo '<h1>' . $row["exercise_id"]. ". " . $row["title"] . '</h1>' . "<br>" . '<p>' . $row["text"] . '</p> <img width="603" height="auto" src="' . $row["image_path"] . '"><br><br>`